# Adding a new line in a textArea with Appcelerator Titanium for iPhone

Tags: line, titanium, appcelerator, break, carriage-return

I have tried both Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT and Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_NEXT,
but neither will add a new line in the text area. Titanium.UI.RETURNKEY_DEFAULT just closes the keyboard.

I see that there was a related bug report here - 
http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-470?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#issue-tabs

It is marked as fixed, but doesn't seem to have been added to the release I'm working with.

Does anyone have a work around for this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this property to your TextArea:

```
suppressReturn: false
```

I tested this with iPhone and can confirm that it works.